# Wordpress　記事表示に関して

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress初心者です。

あるカテゴリーの全記事が表示されるページがあり、その中でアーカイブ毎に表示させるリンクと、そのカテゴリーの中にある子カテゴリー毎のリンクがあるページを作っています。
子カテゴリーのリンクをクリックしてもそのカテゴリーをよみに行ってくれないですが、
アーカイブのほうの記事はよみに行ってくれます。
子カテゴリー毎の記事も表示させたいですが、下記のコードであっていますか？

どなたか教えていただけると助かります。

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'works',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 24,
    'paged' => (get_query_var('page')) ? absint(get_query_var('page')) : 1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'works_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'photo'
        )
    )
);
foreach ($_GET as $k => $v) {
    if (preg_match('/year(2[0-9][0-9][0-9])/', $k, $matches) === 1) {
        $args['year'] = $matches[1];
        break;
    }
}
$works_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/169741

Answer (score 1):

記事公開日付けの年などで絞り込む時は、'date_query'を使います。
詳しくは、https://wpdocs.osdn.jp/%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0%E3%83%AA%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9/WP_Query の　”日付パラメータ” を見て下さい。
以下　2017年で絞り込む例

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'works',
   'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => '2017'
        )
    )
);
```